# MVC3 - Multiple select process for a large list of items

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

Whats the best way to do the following in MVC3 (razor). User needs to pick one more more items from a List and click on button. The list can run into 40 to 100 items. Thats where my problem is, I am looking to see if there is any other solution (other than a list box) to do this more efficiently. Right now, I think I can do this by using a combination(or only one of) of an Auto complete text box and a list box in MVC3.  Also how can I use list box in MVC3 with hard coded list tems.Any suggestions/ideas? Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at using a list search functionality as described in this [post](http://www.msjoe.com/2011/06/ropdown-search-with-jquery/) it uses a jQuery plug in and you could always hook it up through an jquery ajax to get further data back from an MVC action method.

If this doesn't help then let me know and I'll try and put together an example in the morning.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really appreciate the information. An example would be doubly helpful. Looking forward to it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check out "jQuery UI Multiselect" http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/